# Inequality of Complex Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, maximum-principle

My teacher told me this inequality holds but I don't know why:

*Let $f$ be an holomorphic function in an open set containing the closed disk $\overline{D}(z_0,r)$. By Cauchy's Integral formula we have $$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f\big(z_0+re^{it}\big)dt.$$
Therefore,
$$|f(z_0)|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\big|f\big(z_0+re^{it}\big)\big|dt. $$*
By the way, this inequality is used for proving the Maximum Modulus Principle.

Comment: Does this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/y5uKbkSy5K4) help?

Comment: Yes, it has real and complex integration. It should answer your question.

Comment: That's really helpful. Thanks.